# why is play framework timing out?

Tags: playframework

I am starting the the application from the command line using either

```
    activator run 
    activator ~run
```

or after I start the activator console I use run or ~run.
everything seems to work and it gives the expected

```
 --- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

   play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

   (Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)
```

I can view the application in the browser and I can make changes in the code and they are reloaded just fine. the issue is that after only a couple minutes it seems like something "times-out" because if I try to reload after this the browser just sits there spinning.
if i let it spin long enough I get.

```
[error] application - 
[info] 
[info] ! Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->
[info] 
[info] java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [300000 milliseconds]
[info]  at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219) ~[scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na]
[info]  at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223) ~[scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na]
[info]  at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:111) ~[scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na]
[info]  at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53) ~[scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na]
[info]  at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:111) ~[scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na]
```

I would really appreciate any help. Since having to restart the app all over again each time I make a change really takes away the appeal of the framework.

Comment: I would guess that error has something to do with this bug: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/3799

Comment: Interesting thanks for the reply.  I didn't notice anything that specifically mentioned memory issues. But it does sound very similar if not the same. I'll look into performing the heap dump. Thanks.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I upgraded to activator 1.3.2 with Play 2.3.9 and I also had the same issue. It drove me nuts. I found that the cause was the new set "fork in run" setting added in activator 1.3.2.

Open up build.sbt and you will find :

```
fork in run := true
```

Set this to **false** as follows :

```
fork in run := false
```

Comment: I had noticed this line when I started the app before.                        [info] Done updating.
[info] Setting up Play fork run ... (use Ctrl+D to cancel).                      Now that is gone and it seems to be working. That was driving me nuts!

Comment: In addition, stopping run in a fork cosume less memory!

Comment: this was really frustrating and annoying - thanks for the help

Comment: On the annoying scale, this ranks top.  It's basically a broken system if it jams on start.  I've had this happen on three different projects for the last six months.

Comment: On the mailing list I saw a lot of people saying this fixed things. However, what's the purpose of `fork in run`? By setting it to false, will something else not work?

Comment: I had to manually put this value to true in order to debug my application by "-jvm-debug 8000". If it is false, the application will be started in a different jvm which is not the one using debug port.

Comment: What the meaning of that?

Answer (score 0):

Running `activator start` or better `sbt start` fixes the issue as well without having to remove the forking behavior.