# Scala Play SBT is timing out

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I'm just starting to use play. I want to evaluate it for some new development. I'm having some serious performance issue in development. 
I'm doing the excercise from the 'play for java' book. So my example is very simple.

1. SBT takes 2-3 minute to start and for run.
2. When I make a simple change and refresh I'm getting a timeout
   Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [300000 milliseconds]
   [info]  at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
   [info]  at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
   [info]  at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:190)
   [info]  at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
   [info]  at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:190)
   [info]  at play.forkrun.ForkRun$$anonfun$askForReload$1.apply(ForkRun.scala:128)
   [info]  at play.forkrun.ForkRun$$anonfun$askForReload$1.apply(ForkRun.scala:126)
   [info]  at play.runsupport.Reloader$$anonfun$reload$1.apply(Reloader.scala:339)
   [info]  at play.runsupport.Reloader$$anon$3.run(Reloader.scala:44)
   [info]  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

Im using:
Ubuntu: 14.04
Java: 1.8.0_45-b14
scala: 2.11.7
SBT: 0.13.11

UPDATED:
I found the resolution in this post
[why is play framework timing out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241557/why-is-play-framework-timing-out)

Comment: Could you provide a code?
also check if you don't run multiple sbt instances. Turn off and on computer and try again ;)

Comment: I believe I found this issue from this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241557/why-is-play-framework-timing-out. I set 'fork in run : = false' and the problem seems to be resolved. However, I did notice from teh post that I would need to set it to true to debug